# Jekyll Cannot load any post from tags page and categories page?

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll, config

I ve just built a personal blog with **Jekyll and gitpage.**
Firstly it seems working well.But recently I found that both at local and production server, it can not load any post from /tags page and /categories page(these two is ok).I can only load a post from /blog page（the page show all posts).I tried change some configuration in _config.yml, sometimes I succeed loading post but lost the css.Now I have no idea how to fix this?

**at local address these url is Ok:**

```
127.0.0.1:4000

127.0.0.1:4000/#blog

127.0.0.1:4000/2017/How-to-ask/

127.0.0.1:4000/categories/

127.0.0.1:4000/tags/
```

**But at last 2 page, no matter which post I click, the page will lose and the url turns like this:**

```
0.0.7.225/Frequent-errors-when-learning-ruby-on-rails/

0.0.7.225/Linux-command-grep/
```

**Why the prefixed url changes into 0.0.7.225/**

**This is my `_config.yml`**

```
# Site settings
title: Caven's Home
description: 'My home.'
url: 'https://gitcavendish.github.io'
baseurl: '/'
# google_analytics: 'UA-XXXXXX-X'
# disqus_shortname: 'your-disqus-name'

author:
  name: 'Caven'
  email:
  twitter_username:
  facebook_username:
  github_username:  gitCavendish
  linkedin_username:

defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: ''
      type: 'posts'
      values:
      layout: 'post'

# Build settings
destination: _site
paginate: 10
permalink: /:year/:title/
markdown: kramdown
highlighter: rouge

kramdown:
  # use Github Flavored Markdown
  input: GFM
  # do not replace newlines by <br>s
  hard_wrap: false

gems: ['jekyll-paginate']
exclude: ['README.md', 'Gemfile', 'Gemfile.lock', 'screenshot.png']
```

### How to set `_config.yml` to fix this problem?

This is the blog's repo: https://github.com/gitCavendish/gitCavendish.github.io

Comment: Categories and tag pages can not be created with a setting in configuration, they should be generated with a plugin or explicitely creating pages for them.

Comment: @marcnuy Hi marcanuy,thank you for your response. In fact, now the categories page and tags page **already existed and both work well**, my problem is I can't load any post by clicking the post title at these two pages.But I can load post from /blog page.

Comment: I think your site title should have quotes, like this: title: "Caven's Home"

Comment: @JoostS Thank you JoostS， the site title just shows on the browser's tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, change this in the 'categories.html' file:

```
{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}
```

Into this:

```
{{ post.url }}
```

If somebody knows why the earlier statement is wrong, please enlighten me.

Comment: Thanks a lot JoostS. I 've fixed this bug by using your method!

Comment: @Caven: to mark your question as solved, please click the green tick mark adjacent to the answer you prefer, when the system lets you. Thanks!

Comment: @halfer Ok, got it. Thanks!